# Vbscript get object from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript, asp-classic

I get object with javascript like:

```
<script>
$(function() {

$('div.list input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').on('change',onValueChange);     
$('div.selector select').on('change', onValueChange);

function onValueChange() {

        var Checked = {};
        var Selected = {};

        $('div.list input[type=radio]:checked, input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
            var $el = $(this);
            var name = $el.attr('name');
            if (typeof (Checked[name]) === 'undefined') {
                Checked[name] = [];
            }
            Checked[name].push($el.val());
        });

};
});

</script>
```

And now i want to get this object to vbscript variable

```
<%
response.write Ubound(Checked)
%>
```

How to do that?

Comment: Then please show me how to save object to hidden tag?

Comment: You would need to render `Checked` as a string then POST it to ASP then parse out the data.  JSON would be an obvious choice but its not supported in vanilla VBScript/ASP.

Comment: What do you need the VBScript to do that can't be done in JavaScript? In JavaScript the upper boundary of an array can be derived from the `Length` property.

Comment: You should simply need to ensure that the JavaScript rendered control is inside a form.  When the form is submitted the results should be present.